# Setting two increments in a loop that stops at a certain number

Tags: jquery, loops, increment

I have a jQuery function that I need to loop through with two variables that I need to increment up to a certain number. This is the function:

```
var i = 1;
var x = 13;

$('input#question14_' + i).change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.quiz_section.question-section-id-' + x).css('display', 'block')
  } else {
    $('.quiz_section.question-section-id-' + x).css('display', 'none')
  }
});
```

I need `i` to go to `15` and `x` to go to `28` and then stop. Obviously I don't want to write out a function like this for each number but I can't quite figure out how to increment both and loop through.

Comment: How does `i` relate to `x`?

Comment: Don't use looping. DOM traversal is by far the better method to achieve this. If you want to see a concrete example, please edit the question to include your HTML.

Comment: i and x are just numbers in class names/id's of corresponding inputs in a form, they will always be 12 apart. I haven't implemented the loop yet because I'm not sure how to word it yet

Comment: ^ looping is also a bad idea due to creating multiple event handlers in memory that are, for the major part, identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally I would say try to use data elements instead, so you can have a single event handler.  Such that each element could have a `data-id="1"` and a `data-other="13"` that you could reference.  However, you could extract and generate `x` from the id.

```js
//find all the elements who's id begins with question14_
$('input[id^="question14_"]').change(function() {
  //get the number after the _ and add 12
  var x = parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1], 10) + 12;
  
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.quiz_section.question-section-id-' + x).css('display', 'block')
  } else {
    $('.quiz_section.question-section-id-' + x).css('display', 'none')
  }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this is for a Wordpress questionnaire plugin that creates the inputs, so I don't have much control of the output of the html for the form.

Comment: this is not working, if I console.log(x); is says 112